# Shortcut for adding table to column name SQL-server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Stupidly simple question, but I just don't know what to google!

If I create a query like this:

```
Select id, data
from table1
```

Now I want to join with table2. I can immediately see that the id column is no longer unique and I have to change it to

```
table1.id
```

Is there any smart way (like a keyboard-shortcut) to do this, instead of manually adding table1 to every column? Either before I add the Join to secure that all columns will be unique, or after with suggestions based on the different possible tables.

Comment: You need something like Sql prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should start using [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp):

> SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table,
> a temporary name.
>
> Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.

This will narrow down your problem and make your code maintenance easier. If that's not enough, I guess you could start using auto-completion tools, such as these:

1. [SQL Complete](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/)
2. [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/)
3. [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

These have your desired functionality, however, they do not always work as expected (at least for me).

Comment: Thank you, I should definitely use aliases more. I guess the answer to my question is: Not by default but with one of these addons.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no helper.

But do not you can alias the table name:

```
select x.Col1, y.Col2
from ALongTableName x
  inner join AReallyReallyLongTableName y on x.Id = y.OtherId
```

which can also make queries clearer, and is very much necessary when doing self joins.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try to use aliases more.

Answer (score 2):

Oh! You can use alias table name. Like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.data
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

You just only use A. or B. if two table have same this column selected. If they different, you don't need: Like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, data -- if Table B not have column data
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Or:

```
Select A.*, B.ID
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try to use aliases more.